# Dynamically set an asp.net TextBox tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, tooltip

I have an asp.net textbox:

```
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" id="tb" ToolTip="A" />.
```

That I need to be able to set the tooltip based on a value selected from a dropdown list.

```
    If (var == "something") {  
        ToolTip = "B";  
    } else {  
        ToolTip = "A";  
    }
```

I'm setting the ToolTip to an inital value based on what the DropDown defaults to.  When it changes I need to set the ToolTip.

I have seen and tried several solutions from the web, but have been unable to make them work.

I'm using and VS 2008 and IE7, the site is running using the VS server and not IIs.  I have verified that I have the correct field and CAN change the 'title' using the debugger.

Thank You in advance

Comment: Which .net version are you on?

Comment: VS 2008 Framework 3.5, sorry should have mentioned this before.

Comment: Are you trying to do this on client-side or server-side? Is your DDL set to autopostback?

Comment: EVERYTHING is client-side, the person who created the site wanted little if any work being done on the server.  Where this code will reside, is in the client-side function invoked when the DDL changes.

Answer (score 2):

I tried this like this:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID='txtSomething' ToolTip='Some tooltip' CssClass='myTextBox'></asp:TextBox>
```

And in my jQuery I wrote:

```
$(function () {

        var maybe = true;

        if (maybe) {
            $('.myTextBox').attr('title', 'Some other tooltip');
        }

    });
```

And my text box when rendered shows 'Some other tooltip' as its title

Comment: I've tried this and no luck, I even tried forcing it to change all the time.  I noticed the ClientIDMode tag, is that something new in 2010?  I'm on 2008 and do not have it, also does it affect the attr call?

Comment: Still no luck, the '#' notation works in the rest of the code.  I've also tried 'document.getElementById' with no luck.  I've also tried 'tooltip' in place of title, '.tooltip', '.option'.

Comment: It's so strange...do a firebug check on what you get on your page. check if the class name is being applied properly.

Comment: I looked at it VS 2008, I cannot load Firebug as it breaks the machine and is not supported.  It took me several hours with tech support to repair my machine after installing FireFox/Bug.  I could not find mention of tooltip anywhere nor find the inital value loaded.  It did show me the correct field/# variable as I entered data in the field.

Comment: I just noticed your CssClass='myTextBox'.  What is your code for this as I do not have a CssClass created for my textbox.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this using jQuery:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#<%=DropDownList1.ClientID %>").change(function () {
                var tooltip = "B";
                var val = $(this).val();
                if (val == "One") {
                    tooltip = "A";
                }
                $("#<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>").attr('title', tooltip);
            });
        });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Text="One" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="Two" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="Three" />
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" ToolTip="A"></asp:TextBox>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Update - class selector way:

```
$(function () {
            $('.myddl').change(function () {
                var tooltip = "B";
                var val = $(this).val();
                if (val == "One") {
                    tooltip = "A";
                }
                $('.mytb').attr('title', tooltip);
            });
        });

 <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" CssClass="myddl">

 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" ToolTip="A" CssClass="mytb"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: Even using the "#<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>" notation would not change the tooltip.  For some reason that I cannot fathom, the code will not/can not access the textbox control.  Looking at the "#TB" in the VS debugger, it's telling me the attributes are null; if I tried to change the tooltip by "#tb.attributes['title']" I got a runtime error.  Document.getelementbyID returned null.  I've tried using 1.5 JQuery with no effect.  Something is preventing JQuery from modifying the ToolTip.

Comment: I expect it does.  How are you running your code?  IIs or in Visual Studio?

Comment: Visual Web Developer Express and I am sure it wouldn't make any difference when run on IIS.

Comment: They do work in different ways.  I worked on a project in which I did all my development using IIs, all of the 'add-ins' that I was required to use had been tested using VS.  NONE of them worked!  The enviroment in this position will not allow for IIs to be used on my machine.

Comment: If you have VS or VWD Express 2010, you might want to try IIS Express. VWD and IIS express are free. For whatsoever reason if the clientID format didn't work you can try the class selector version. Check my another code-snippet.

Comment: I have tried your varriant using both the "." and "#" notations.  The problem has more to do with the .attr() not working.  The enviroment I'm working in is tightly controlled due to being in the financial sector, so downloading something...

Comment: Ok what error are you getting with attr?? Are you able to use jquery?

Comment: UsingMicrosoft JScript runtime error: 'Attributes' is null or not an object

Comment: It is hard to say what exactly is causing that. Are you sure it is this part of javascript and not something else?. Can you post your code or may be a sample that you tried and shows the error.

Comment: Using '.attr' I get no error, it just does nothing.  Using ".Attributes['title']" I get:  "Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'Attributes' is null or not an object".  Looking at it in the debugger, it says attributes is null and i do not see the inital tooltip anywhere.  IF I dig down into sub "children" I find a title which does not have the inital tooltip, but if I change it it displays the new tooltip.  I'm debugging using VS 2008 on IE7.  The site has so much Jquery it qualifies as a WinApp.  I also make sure the TB is visible as I thought this might be a problem.

Comment: My original example is exactly my code minus style="width: auto" on the textbox aspx line.

Comment: You know right you cannot use .Attributes["title"] in javascript?

Comment: This is JQuery and I will try anything in case it happens to work.

Comment: What I am saying is:  $('.mytb').Attributes["title"] = "ABAC"; will not work. From your description, the first code-block in my post does that exactly and it works. Can you create a new .aspx page and try that code. If it does not work, please post the code in that page and I will be happy to test it out.

Comment: I created a new project with 1 page having a DDL and TB.  It worked perfectly.  I went back to my problem site and added "<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>", this caused a LOT of things to break.  This leads me to think whoever created this site made changes to the Jquery*.js as there is a local copies that are loaded by the page/site.

Comment: May be the jquery files on your site is older version but again, new versions are backward compatible. And even is someone changed, I doubt them changing the core functionality used in the sample code above.

Comment: It is an older version '1.4.2', but given what has been done on this site, I would not be suprised if the core code was modified.  They may have also put a tweak in the CSS that broke something.  All I know is that when I put the 1.5.2 reference in, entire divs and fields were displayed that normally are hidden, it complained about a .footer in the CSS file, also the change of the ToolTip still did not work.  I have another way I can do this, involving 2 textboxs - displaying them depending on what is choosen in the DDL; this approach is consistant with all the rest of the page/site.

Answer (score 0):

The code I have listed in my question works and does change ToolTips.  The problem lies with the person who created the site and his machinations of CSS and Javascript/JQuery/Json; somehow the ability to access ToolTips was disabled.

Comment: I finally got it to work, the problem was how the control was referenced. Using either '.mytb' or '#mytb' failed, I needed to use '[id$=mytb]'.